# htaccess authentication only in certain subfolder

Tags: git, .htaccess, authentication, subdirectory

I have these folders:

```
root/
    dev/ => dev.example.com
    live/ => example.com
```

The dev folder needs user authentication, the live folder doesn't. Originally both folders have their own `.htaccess` file which are almost the same, only in live the user authentication part is removed.

The contents of the live folder are pulled from the dev folder - in the future, I want to use git for that and pull all of the files and folders to live - including the `.htaccess` - but I dont want to remove the user authentication in the live folder .

What I want to achieve is, having an `.htaccess` file in the root folder that only consists of the user authentification:

```
AuthUserFile /www/htdocs/root/dev/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName 'ByPassword'
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

And I want to have a second `.htaccess` in the dev folder, that consists of the rest of the info that are needed. I want that `root/.htaccess` only contains the password to protect my dev folder - so that when I pull the content from dev to live (including the `.htaccess` file in the dev folder), I dont have to change anything in the live folder.

I researched on this and couldn't really find anything for that special scenario, and I'm not really proficient in that `.htaccess` stuff, so I hope you might have some help/suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With apache 2.4 you can do:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'dev.example.com'">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "restricted area"
  AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
  require valid-user
</If>
```

see all expressions at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html